# Changes not made to a dataframe after a for cycle

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

first question around so please be patient (as I'm also a newbie to python and pandas).

I'm trying to make some changes on two dataframes as below:

```
dfs = [data,prev_data]

for df in dfs:
...
    print(len(df))
    df = df[~df['column'].isin(['X','Y'])]
    print(len(df))
```

the print output is

```
271
162
654
396
```

but after closing the cycle, if I use

```
print(len(data))
print(len(prev_data))
```

the result is the first print again

```
271
654
```

As it's only two dataframes I've opted for two separated codes to solve the issue, but as there's more code in the cycle any change made needs to be done twice.

I've tested all the code before and the difference is in this part. If needed I can copy it here.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: In the for loop the updated dataframe `df` has to be stored somewhere. Are you doing this?

Comment: Hey Davide, thanks. I am not. I assumed ``df = df[~df['column'].isin(['X','Y'])]`` would be interpreted as something like ``data = data[~data['column'].isin(['X','Y'])]``. Maybe that's the mistake.

Comment: You never change the data frame that data or prev_data point to so they will still be the same as before the cycle

Comment: data is just a name that points to the dataframe. When you iterate your loop you create a new name called df that points to the same dataframe, so now you have two names that point to the same data frame. When you do `df = df[~df['column'].isin(['X','Y'])]` you are saying make a new data frame and now point df at that data frame. That doesnt change the data frame that data points to. It still points to the original one

Comment: Thanks @ChrisDoyle for your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store the updated data frames in a new list, like this:

```
dfs = [data,prev_data]
new_dfs =[]
for df in dfs:
...
    print(len(df))
    df = df[~df['column'].isin(['X','Y'])]
    new_dfs.append(df)  
    print(len(df))     

print(len(new_dfs[0]) #updated data
print(len(new_dfs[1]) #updated prev_data
```